# Swift generic constraint on method does not behave as expected when called from instance

Tags: swift, generics

Here is the following piece of Swift code:

```
class HTTP {
    func run<T: Decodable>(handler: (Result<T, Error>) -> Void) {
        HTTP.handle(handler: handler)
    }
}

extension HTTP {
    static func handle<T: Decodable>(handler: (Result<T, Error>) -> Void) {
        Swift.print("Base")
    }
}

extension HTTP {
    static func handle<T: Decodable & Offline>(handler: (Result<T, Error>) -> Void) {
        Swift.print("Offline")
    }
}

protocol Offline {
    associatedtype Data
    var data: Data { get set }
}

struct Model: Decodable, Offline {
    var data: String = "abc..."
}

let h1 = HTTP()
h1.run { (r: Result<[String], Error>) in }        // 1 - Print "Base" => OK

let h2 = HTTP()
h2.run { (r: Result<Model, Error>) in }           // 2 - Print "Base" => ???

HTTP.handle { (r: Result<[String], Error>) in }   // 3 - Print "Base" => OK

HTTP.handle { (r: Result<Model, Error>) in }      // 4 - Print "Offline" => OK
```

I am trying to figure out why in case 2, it prints "Base" instead of "Offline". If anyone has suggestions so the right `handle` method get called depending on the given type **T**.

I made the `handle` method static for demo/running purpose to show it works in a static context (case 3 and 4). As you can see, called from the HTTP instance context behaviour is different (case 2).

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the instance function `run(handler:)` because it sets as a constraint the `T` to be only `Decodable`, filters in some way the `Offline` constraint. So, passes a type that is only `Decodable` to the static function `handle(handler:)` and the compiler assumes that the callable function is the one with only `Decodable` as a constraint.I do not know if this is understandable.

You can have the expected behavior by adding an overload for your instance function in `HTTP` class:

```
class HTTP {
    func run<T: Decodable>(handler: (Result<T, Error>) -> Void) {
        HTTP.handle(handler: handler)
    }
    
    func run<T: Decodable & Offline>(handler: (Result<T, Error>) -> Void) {
        HTTP.handle(handler: handler)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah that's the solution I came up with, even if not perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The correct `HTTP.handle` to call is decided at compile time, and baked into the binary. `T` is only promised to be `Decodable` in `run`. It might conform to other protocols, but that's all that's promised. So it compiles this into a call to the `Decodable` version, even if you call it with something that *could* be `Offline`.

This gets to the point of generic specializations. It's not intended to change behavior. It's intended generally to improve performance. For example, consider the following:

```
func f<Seq: Sequence>(_ seq: Seq) -> Bool { ... }
func f<Seq: RandomAccessCollection>(_ seq: Seq) -> Bool { ... }
```

Every RandomAccessCollection is a Sequence, so one or the other might be called for an Array. Both should *always* return the same result. But the second might be more efficient in cases where the system can prove that Seq is Array. If they returned different results, it's not going to work correctly.

Generics are not a way to reinvent class inheritance. If you really need class inheritance, then use classes and inheritance. But generally you should redesign your system to avoid that. How to do that depends on the real goal here.

Comment: Yes you are right. Unfortunately, there is some cases where the only solution is to use generics. Here, I am implementing an HTTP client and wants it to be able to decode any type of response/model. In such a case, class inheritance is not an option. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: The point wasn't that you require class inheritance (you can build this without generics *or* inheritance; C has built these kinds of systems for decades). The point is that what you're doing here (including in the accepted answer) is trying to reinvent inheritance with generics by changing behavior based on generic overloads (rather than class-based overrides). Overloads don't solve the same problems. For an example of a generics-based system that handles arbitrary APIs, see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DXwJg0QTlZE This is what I meant by "you should redesign your system to avoid that."

Comment: Will have a look. Thanks !